# Sentencia para un inner join a dos campos de una tabla

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo las Tablas A y B. En B tengo dos campos que contienen los Ids de A para hacer relaciones en un reporte de php. Sin embargo me encuentro con un problema: que no puedo hacer un `INNER JOIN` para mostrar esos dos campos;

```
TABLA-A
id      Nombre
================
 1      Andres
 2      Juan
```

---

```
TABLA-B
id      id_Primer_persona      id_Segunda_persona
===================================================
1       1                      2
```

Bien entonces, tengo esas dos tablas. En A tengo los datos de la persona y B es una tabla que puede tener dos personas por registro (estas tablas son de ejemplo; las reales tienen muchos datos y no puedo cambiar el desarrollo). Normalmente haría este `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT tablaB.id, tablaA.nombre as Nombre1 
FROM tablaB
INNER JOIN tablaA on tablaA.id = tablaB.id_Primer_persona
```

Resultado:

```
id nombre1
==========
1  Andres
```

Ese código funciona para sacar la primera persona, pero entonces, si quiero sacar un registro que me muestre el nombre de la primera y segunda persona, ¿cómo lo hago? Gracias.

Comment: Un detalle: Al parecer cambiaste los nombres de las tablas. `TablaA` es la que contiene la columna `Nombre`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haz un `INNER JOIN` a `TablaA` dos veces, con distintos alias:

```
SELECT
    tablaB.id,
    tablaA1.nombre as nombre1,
    tablaA2.nombre as nombre2
FROM tablaB 
INNER JOIN tablaA as tablaA1 on tablaA1.id = tablaB.id_primer_persona
INNER JOIN tablaA as tablaA2 on tablaA2.id = tablaB.id_segunda_persona;
```

Eso te daría el resultado:

```
id    nombre1    nombre2
========================
1     Andres     Juan
```

Esto sólo funcionaría si existen ambos ID en la fila de `tablaB`; si no lo hubiera, tendrías que ajustar la consulta usando `LEFT JOIN`, quizás.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a penas pueda marcarla como como mejor respeusta lo hago, Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que yo haria es hacer n JOINS a la misma tabla te deberia de funcionar asi:

```
SELECT A.id, B.nombre as Nombre1,  
FROM tablaA AS A
INNER JOIN tablaB AS B on A.id = B.id_Primer_persona
INNER JOIN tablaA AS A2 on A.id = B.id_Segunda_persona
```

Answer (score 2):

Usalo Así:

```
SELECT
    tablaB.id,
    tablaA1.nombre as nombre1,
    tablaA2.nombre as nombre2
FROM tablaB 
INNER JOIN tablaA as tablaA1 on (tablaA1.id = tablaB.id_primer_persona and tablaA1.id = tablaB.id_segunda_persona);
```